# Mongo DB, count documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Is there a way to query mongoDB in order to get counted documents with certain date?
As for example, I have documents:

```
[{
fullDate: '2020/02/01',
someData: 'someData',
},
{
fullDate: '2020/03/01',
someData: 'someData',
},
{
fullDate: '2020/03/01',
someData: 'someData',
},
{
fullDate: '2020/02/01',
someData: 'someData',
},
{
fullDate: '2020/02/01',
someData: 'someData',
},
{
fullDate: '2020/02/01',
someData: 'someData',
}]
```

I would like to make counting query to get info that there are 4 documents with fullDate of 2020/02/01 and 2 documents with fullDate of 2020/02/03 in one query. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a simple [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$fullDate",
            count: {$sum: 1}
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Btw, can I filter it first?

Comment: Yep, just add a `$match` stage before.